# Android SQLite database not updating using pre populated sqlite database have to unstall and reinstall

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my question. I have a app I have uploaded to the Google play store. The app works fine until it gets to the part where I added new records to my database for a level I created in a pre-populated sqlite database, when I get to this particular level it crashes. Like the new information was not created. the code is below. I have read that I need to create a version variable and increment it, in the onupgrade() method. but I am new to this sqlite learning. If I create a version variable will the code keep track of it?, do I have to rename the database with a version number, please help.

I have tried following the following this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727137/updating-sqlite-database-android), and it seems to be what I am looking for, but my question is looking at that the example is the versioning all done within code or do I have to append a version number to my *.db file.

```
package com.xtremeware.straighthoodtrivia.db;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.xtremeware.straighthoodtrivia.quiz.Question;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{   
// The androids's default system path of the application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.xtremeware.straighthoodtrivia    /databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "QuestionsDb";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

// Constructor
// Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the 
// applications assets and resources.
// @ context

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

// Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with my own database
public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!dbExist)
    {
        // By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
        // of my application so I am gonna be able to overwrite the database with my database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
         try 
         {
             copyDataBase();
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
             throw new Error("Error copying database");
         }
    }
}

// Check if the database already exists to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
// @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't

private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try
    {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        // Database doesn't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null)
    {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

// Copies the database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in 
// the system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
// This is done by transferring bytestreams.

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the empty db just created
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close()
{
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put something like:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

in your DBHelper class.

And then implementations of your constructor, and the onCreate and onUpgrade methods like:

```
   DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("create table existing_table...");
      db.execSQL("create table new_table...");
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ".");
      //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
      if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion >= 2){
         db.execSQL("alter table existing_table add column new_column integer not null default -1;");
         db.execSQL("create table new_table (...)");
      }
   }
```

The versioning is done in the code, but the version code is passed in the super(...) call jn the DBHelper constructor, which takes care of making sure the database is aware of its current version. You do not have to append the version number yourself to your "*.db" file.

Basically, by comparing the oldVersion and the newVersion you decide which scripts to run on the upgrade.
However, for new app installs, you just make sure the onCreate version creates the up to date tables right away.

Next time to you want to publish a version of your app that needs an update to the table structure, you increment the value of your DATABASE_VERSION field, and change the onUpgrade as required.

Comment: I have tried that and many more things. I changed the DB_VERSION to 2 it was 1, and in the onUpgrade function this is what I have. @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ".");
  
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_NAME);
 if(oldVersion == 1 && newVersion >= 2)
 {
  db.execSQL("Create table new_table (...)");
 }
}

Comment: When I go look at the logcat this is what I get. 09-11 10:40:13.161: E/AndroidRuntime(3618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main


09-11 10:40:13.161: E/AndroidRuntime(3618): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
09-11 10:40:13.161: E/AndroidRuntime(3618):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-11 10:40:13.161: E/AndroidRuntime(3618):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)

Comment: Ok so I am at a loss, here is the situation the database I created was done in sqlite database browser 2.0 b1win, when I created the database it has two tables, android_metadata with one filed locale with a text object type, and it has my questions table, so when I save the database back in the assets folder after making changes, the version number does not get incremented, should it be a field or table for version number or am I using something obsolete. I have tried everything

Comment: Doing more research it doesn't look like my database is being incremented when I save it. where do I find where the database is getting incremented, does this happen automatically each time I save the updated database. I open it up in sqlite database browser make changes then resave it back to the assets folder, no where is there a place where I can see that it has been incremented.